# How to export table data from sql stored procedure to .csv in SSMS (without using BCP)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have a DB "Test" and table "demo"(TRANSACT TYPE,TRANSACT_NUMBER,BALANCE,CREDIT AMOUNT,ACCOUNTING_DATE).
my purpose is:

- to create a procedure which exports all the data of the table "demo" to csv file (**without using bcp utility**)

So far i have written the following code for stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test1 
AS

   SELECT * FROM demo

GO
EXEC Test1
```

and the following script in which I used the bcp utility (which gets an error: *SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file*):

```
DECLARE @ExportFolderName NVARCHAR(90);
DECLARE @ExportFileName NVARCHAR(90);

SET @ExportFolderName = 'C:\Export\';
SET @ExportFileName = @ExportFolderName + 'demofile' + '.csv';

DECLARE @SqlStatement varchar(8000)
DECLARE @BcpStatement varchar(8000)

SET @SqlStatement = 'exec [SInterface].[dbo].[Test1]'
SET @BcpStatement = 'bcp "' +@SqlStatement + '" queryout "' + @ExportFileName + '" -c -t","-r"\n" -T'

exec master..xp_cmdshell @BcpStatement
```

for this reason I try to find a solution in which bcp is not used

Comment: I always dislike the idea of using SQL Sever, to call command line, to call BCP, to call SQL Server, and extract the data; there's so many middle men, it's clunky, and it required `sysadmin` privileges. Rather than using a clunky way in SQL Server to effectively create a "push", why not use a different tool to *pull* the data from the SQL server and create the CSV?

Comment: The reason why you're struggling to find a solution here is that the concept sort of violates the "design philosophy" of the database. SQL Server is not designed as a platform to push data out. it's designed as a platform from which to read data, and then manipulate it in some way. BCP is a tool which can do that.. it can read data, and then "manipulates it" - for example by writing it out to a file. There are lots of other tools that can do that. You can write a web application, a windows forms application, an SSIS package, a windows service... etc etc